# YTPlayerView once loaded opens the video in youtube app

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

So the title pretty much sums up the situation I am loading my YTPlayerView like this:

```
[self.videoView loadWithVideoId:@"youtube id"];
```

And like it was mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) it works perfectly however the second time I tap on the view the video opens on the youtube app sometimes and not on fullscreen.

Any help here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I didn't find an answer to this question so I decided to dig on the YTPlayerView.m file and see how the touch event is handled and I found that there is two ways to do this:

**1-** the YTPlayerView contains a webView and an override of:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This is the full code which checks the url scheme to trigger the appropriate action

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  if ([request.URL.host isEqual: self.originURL.host]) {
    return YES;
  } else if ([request.URL.scheme isEqual:@"ytplayer"]) {
    [self notifyDelegateOfYouTubeCallbackUrl:request.URL];
    return NO;
  } else if ([request.URL.scheme isEqual: @"http"] || [request.URL.scheme isEqual:@"https"]) {
    return [self handleHttpNavigationToUrl:request.URL];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

which was in my case this function **handleHttpNavigationToUrl** that returns a bool which indicates if the video should open on the app or the youtube application.
I have commented these lines that opens the video on the app and everything is ok now.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
```

This is a quick fix and not good one i know but in my case i had no choice the 2nd solution is much better though.

**2-** The problem is in the youtube url in the first place as if you are using the embed url this problem will not occur,
so instead try to use other methods for loading the video by using the embed url, which is of the format:

**http(s)://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEO ID]?[PARAMETERS]**

so just try to use **loadVideoByURL** and use the embed url instead of **loadWithVideoId**.
Voila i hope this helps.